# Arabic Font Is not fully applied?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to add ge-ss-two-medium font to my Arabic HTML Page but strangely enough I can only see the font getting actually changed in a letter or 2 while the whole remaining strings and numbers on my website are still on the default font

- I've tried to get the font file from other websites assuming that the issue is in the file but the problem still the same also I checked that my url value with @fontface is correct. tried to open in from other browsers and still there
- I've tried to get the font file from other websites assuming that the issue is in the file but the problem still the same also I checked that my url value with @fontface is correct. tried to open in from other browsers and still there

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "GE SS Two Medium";
  src: url("ge-ss-two/GE_SS_Two_Medium.eot?") format("eot"), url("ge-ss-two/GE_SS_Two_Medium.woff") format("woff"), url("ge-ss-two/GE_SS_Two_Medium.ttf") format("truetype"), url("ge-ss-two/GE_SS_Two_Medium.svg#GESSTwoMedium-Medium") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "GE SS Two Medium";
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container overflow-hidden">
  <img src="img/shal.jpg">
  <div class="text">
    <h4>أفضل الشماغات</h4>
    <h1>&#65260; </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

also I've tried to use specified IDs, classes, and !important instead of the wildly applied *

[image: Broken Font]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/SRtqmHj/Screenshot-11.png))</sub>

this is how it looks on my pc. the letters with the green underline are showing the right font while the rest do not! how can I fix this ??!

Update: Screen shot from mplungjan's Chrome 71

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about your characters? Maybe they're Persian characters from a non-Arabic keyboard.

Comment: Looks OK on my Chrome but I cannot read it - The / هـ / ـهـ / ـه looks different in my Chrome with my fonts (I see the middle one)

Comment: @mrReiha yes I'm sure they are arabic

Comment: @mplungjan can you share a screenshot with me?

Comment: See update to your question

Comment: Is there the same problem when you use other fonts?

Comment: @mplungjan this is the letter without the font at all!

Comment: @mrReiha only with any custom font

Comment: I would say there's a problem with your font then.